# Generator won't start cold - compression release bad?

Tags: small-engine, generator

I bought a brand new generator (an AIPower GXS7100iRD) late last year. From day 1, it was incredibly difficult to start cold. It would require being cranked until the battery was nearly dead before it would backfire a couple times and then start. Once started, it purred like a kitten and worked perfectly. And if it was warm, it would start immediately. I arranged for warranty service and the diagnosis from the shop was a bad compression release and the manufacturer sent me a new generator. The new one functions perfectly.

So this isn't a problem that needs solving, I just want to understand this diagnosis.

My understanding is that compression release systems are designed to make it easier to crank the engine before it starts, and that once it starts it is disabled. Given that the engine ran properly once it started, wouldn't that indicate that the compression release was out/off once the engine was running? Wouldn't that mean that the only flaw that could be present would be that it was stuck off? And wouldn't that make it much harder to pull? So far as I can tell the electric start had no trouble cranking it and pulling the recoil was not any more difficult than I would expect it to be.

How does this diagnosis make sense?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You had put your question on our Meta site, so moved it over here to the main site, which is were the question belongs :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that the engine ran properly once it started, wouldn't that
> indicate that the compression release was out/off once the engine was
> running?

Yes, you've got that right. When it was running at 3600 RPM the compression release was disengaged. And when you were trying to start, it was engaged / compression was released, so it didn't seem extra hard to pull-start.

I think the defect was *not* that compression release was stuck on or off; the defect must have been a mis-calibration of the RPM at which it would stop releasing compression. It was set too high, such as by a spring being too strong, too short or hooked into the wrong hole among a series of holes.

The engine won't run under its own power if compression is always released because, uh, let's see: it has no compression! Compression release simply holds open one of the valves so that no pressure can build up in the cylinder during the compression stroke. The defective generator may have had its compression release calibrated such that it just barely started allowing compression at the top speed of the starter with cold oil. A warmed-up engine has less viscous oil, so the starter can spin the engine faster, and for the defective generator that was fast enough to surpass the compression release cutoff speed.

Suppose for the sake of argument compression release is supposed to be engaged (compression-released) at any speed under 100 RPM. This allows the starter or a pull-start to get going and build up some rotational momentum. Then as soon as compression release is disengaged (compression is allowed) at the arbitrary 100 RPM, the slowdown from each compression stroke is paid back by a speed-up from the built-up compression in the cylinder after top dead center. The engine can now turn faster and faster until it catches.

I have a diesel generator with a manual compression release lever. Compression is so high that you absolutely can not pull-start it unless you engage the compression release. But it self-disengages after just a single rotation of the crankshaft. It's not RPM sensitive. But one rotation is enough to build up enough momentum to overcome the super-high compression of the diesel engine and get that compression energy back after TDC. (Truthfully, electric start is much less painful!)

Comment: That also, perhaps, explains its propensity to backfire just before managing to start.